# Android studio always reloads after losing focus?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an Android app. When I open the app, it loads and I am able to use it no problems. If I then minimize the app, and come back, the whole app restarts and reloads everything.

1. Is there some kind of list of things I can check for to try and figure out why this is happening?
2. Is there perhaps some "dont reload app after losing focus" setting I am not aware of?
3. Any other suggestions on how to figure out why my Android app would be doing this?

**THEORY 1**

I have a base class called MyApplication. This class is where I store all the info for the app. So the user info, the items to display etc. I expose this using static functions:

```
public static List<UserNotification> getUserNotifications(Context context) {
    return userNotifications;
}
```

My theory is that somehow, when losing focus, this base class is destroyed. Perhaps through garbage collecting? I'm not sure. Which also builds up to another question...

4. If storing info like this on my base class is wrong, what is the correct way to deal with this so as to avoid the user having to reload everything each time he opens the app?

Answer (score 1):

[App life cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uadzP.jpg)

To not loose your data you need to use the Bundle savedInstance
using the onSaveInstanceState method

I recommend you to log as most as possible to have a global view of what's going on and the order of all the log and methods